# subquery NOT IN in Pig

Tags: join, subquery, apache-pig

How to do a not-in subquery in Pig ? 
i.e.

```
mysql> SELECT ArticleTitle, Copyright
    -> FROM Articles
    -> WHERE Copyright NOT IN
    ->    (
    ->       SELECT b.copyright
    ->       FROM Articles AS b JOIN AuthorArticle AS ab USING (ArticleID)
    ->         
    ->       WHERE AuthorLastName='Yin'
```

Right now i have the subquery (a Join), but i am not sure how to get articles that DO NOT belong in that subquery. I tried using a FILTER BY article NOT IN myJoin , but myJoin is a bag, and IN expects a tuple of scalars.
Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `LEFT OUTER` (or `FULL OUTER`) join, then any cases where `Copyright` is null in the field drawn from the subquery satisfy what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks; I ended up doing pretty much what you are saying, doing a left outer join and doing a FOREACH with a condition statement on null ..

Cheers, Matt